# Passing Ionicon name as props and using it in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionicons

So I am building an Ionic App with Vue, and I just happen to get stuck on this one particular problem.
where I am receiving an array of objects, and one of the field in that object is `icon-name`,

Now what I don't know or rather have an issue with is how do I use that `icon-name` field to show the desired icon

As Per documentation, One of the way is that I can add a **`<script src>`** tag inside of the Index.html and then use **`name={{item.icon-name}}`** but the problem here is that I get the following error in the browser console

> **Failed to load module  The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of “text/html”. Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.**

Second way is that i `Import {iconName} from "ionicons/icons"` and return it in  `data()`
in this way the issue is I do not know first hand what icon-name will be passed to me in the array.

Please Suggest..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]